# How to Install Java Darcula look and feel?

Tags: java, netbeans-8, look-and-feel

I want to install the Darcula look and feel so I can change the appearece of my Java projects.

I executed this code to know which look and feels I have installed:

```
for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        System.out.println("Look: " + info.getName());
    }
```

The console shows that I don't have Darcula. Only these ones:

```
Look: Metal
Look: Nimbus
Look: CDE/Motif
Look: GTK+
```

I downloaded this https://github.com/bulenkov/Darcula and I added to my project as a library. But I am not sure if it is the right approach.

I use Netbeans 8.2.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Tools > Plugins' action from the NetBeans IDE main menu for a convenient installation of this plugin. You can search for Darcula, hit install, wait a moment and you're ready to go!

Comment: If my answer helped you, you can upvote it and accept it as an answer to you question!

Comment: It changes the IDE interface but not the program made with the IDE.

Comment: Oh, i see what you're trying to do now. This is a wrong approach friend. The Look&Feel of your IDE should not be confused with the Look&Feel of your apps (which is mainly used to set the look & feel of a program to resemble the system). You'll have to create something similar yourself for your GUI. If you want it to resemble Darcula, you can use dark grey backgrounds and dark red/yellow/orange tints all across the app.

Comment: You can also take a look [here](http://www.jwrapper.com/blog/6-great-look-and-feels-to-make-your-java-app-pretty) to see some themes for Java Swing. If i was of any help understanding the difference, consider upvoting/accepting this answer.